# How I can make route API in Laravel with parameter

Tags: laravel, api

my route:

```
Route::get('page/{key_id_fk}', 'PagesApiController@show');
```

my function:

```
public function show($key_id_fk)
{
    $sub=DefintionDetails::find($key_id_fk);

  //  $main=Definition::where([['type','=',1],['available','=',1],['id_definition','=',$sub->id_def]])->get();
    return response()->json($sub , 200);
}
```

on post man route is `page?key_id_fk=1` give error 404 not found key in data base but didn't read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the route file:

```
    Route::get('page/{key_id_fk}', 'PagesApiController@show');
```

In the controller:

```
public function show($key_id_fk){

    $sub = DefintionDetails::find($key_id_fk); 

    if($sub){
       return response()->json(['success' => true, 'sub' => $sub]);
    } else {
       return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error_message' => 'No data found!']);
    }
}
```

Your postman route:

```
http://example.com/page/1
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be accessing `page/1` rather than `page?key_id_fk=1` as you are not using parameter queries in your request url.

Your route format is `page/$key_id_fk`.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `key_id_fk` as `http://example.com/page/1` in route and passing parameter as `http://example.com/page?key_id_fk=1` difference is first one is **URL route data** and second is **GET parameter data** to get data from URL route you have this `public function show($key_id_fk)` and to get data from GET parameter `public function show(Request $request)` and `$request->key_id_fk`.

so change URL to this `http://example.com/page/1` format 
or
change getting method in the controller to `public function show(Request $request)` and `$request->key_id_fk`